# Storage of data costs more than expected

Tags: solidity, gas

I have a simple contract looking like this:

```
contract storage {
   bytes32 data;

   function f(uint256 _a, uint256 _b) public {
      bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(_a, _b));
      data = hash;
   }
}
```

and I would like to understand why calling the function f costs around 44k gas because I read that SSTORE costs at most 22k gas. Where does the gas cost comes from?
Thank you.

Comment: Transactions use a minimum 21k gas, add for SSTORE 20k then is quite close to 44k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have some of the most relevant operations in terms of gas consuption

let's suppose you send a transaction to the function f passing 1 and 2 as _a and _b respectively

that means that you will have the following input:

0x13d1aa2e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002

function selector: *0x13d1aa2e*

parameter _a: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

parameter _b: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002

if you take a look at the [ethereum yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (page 27) you will see: how much you will pay for the following operations:

Gtxdatazero 4 (unit of gas) Paid for every zero byte of data or code for a transaction.
Gtxdatanonzero 16 (unit of gas) Paid for every non-zero byte of data or code for a transaction

0x13d1aa2e (function selector) 4 non-zero bytes => 4 * 16 (unit of gas) = **64**

parameter _a: 31 zero bytes + 1 non-zero bytes => 31 * 4 + 1 * 16 = **140**

parameter _b: 31 zero bytes + 1 non-zero bytes => 31 * 4 + 1 * 16 = **140**

Gkeccak256 30 Paid for each KECCAK256 operation.
Gkeccak256word 6 Paid for each word (rounded up) for input data to a KECCAK256 operation

---

keccak256(abi.encode(_a, _b));

the result of abi.encode(_a, _b) is:

0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002

meaning two words as input of keccak256

30 Paid for each KECCAK256 operation  => **30**

6 Paid for each word (rounded up) for input data to a KECCAK256 operation => 6 * 2 = **12**

---

Gsset **20000** Paid for an SSTORE operation when the storage value is set to non-zero from zero
Gcoldsload **2100** Cost of a cold storage access (first time you access a state variable in a transaction)

Gtransaction **21000** Paid for every transaction

additionally you can debug it using remix and check every opcode executed and [here](https://www.evm.codes/?fork=arrowGlacier) you can see how much gas it cost

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer! My main mistake was ignoring the existence of Gtransaction.

Answer (score 0):

The most typical reason is storage of data. If you change the value of a previously non-set variable to a set variable, the transaction costs more than resetting the value of the same variable.